# Display friendly message when ExecutorService is shutting down in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

So, I v 've a code for shutting down executor service in Java as under -

```
public void shutdownExecutor() {
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(requestInfo.getUploadThreadCount() * 30,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

In the code above, as you see the client application (either console or web) goes blank until thread count * 30 seconds are run out. How do I display a friendly message here instead?

Comment: Add `System.out.println("Friendly message");` before the call to `awaitTermination`? (It's not clear the sense in which you need a message to be "friendly")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to display a periodic message whilst waiting, you can do it like so (e.g. displaying a message every 1 second up to a maximum of 30 seconds):

```
try {
  long endTime = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(30);
  while (true) {
    long timeout = Math.min(
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1), endTime - System.nanoTime());
    if (timeout <= 0
        || executor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)) {
      break;
    }
    System.err.println("Still waiting for timeout");
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  logger.error(e);
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example, I've blocked the executor for 10 seconds to test.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
executor.submit(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
executor.shutdown();
System.out.println("The executor is shutting down, "+
                   "why not make yourself a cup of tea whilst you wait?");
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
```